# How to initialize mongodb session with specified projectid and manage sessions and jobs

Tags: java, mongodb

For Google Firestore, there is documentation available on how to initialize Firestore client with specific project I'd, like in the below link :
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-setup-client-create#firestore_setup_client_create-java

Also, we can use following lines of code for handling sessions/jobs

```
FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions =
    FirestoreOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId(projectId).build();

Session = firestoreOptions.getService().collection("Sessions");

Job = firestoreOptions.getService().collection("Jobs");
```

What are the equivalent lines of code for Mongodb in Java ? How can we replace these functions with mongodb ones without breaking the existing code ?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/java/sync/v4.3/fundamentals/connection/connect/?